# Prove set is dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is a pretty basic and general question.
I have to prove (if true) that the sum of two dense sets is dense as well.

> Let $A, B$ be nonempty dense sets in $\mathbb R$. Then $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ is also dense.

Can anyone give me a pointer as to how one may prove this (just the method)? is it algebraic or with $\sup /\inf/\text{sequences}$ etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I’ve assumed in my answer that by *dense* you mean *dense in* $\Bbb R$, but it occurs to me that you might mean that $A$ and $B$ are dense in themselves (i.e., have no isolated point), and that you want to show that $A+B$ is dense in itself. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I've deleted the comment as you are one of the others I meant. I should get more sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Let $x\in\Bbb R$ be arbitrary. Pick any $a\in A$, and find a sequence $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $B$ converging to $x-a$.

(All that you need for the conclusion is that one of $A$ and $B$ be dense and the other non-empty.)

Comment: Why do we need the other to be non empty? Wouldn't $A+\emptyset = A$ also be dense?

Comment: @Relsiark: $A+\varnothing=\{a+x:a\in A\text{ and }x\in\varnothing\}=\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I didn't quite get that. Let's say $x=5$, $\ 0<$ A $<2$ and $10<$ B $<12$.

For $a \in A\  $ I choose $1$. How can I find a sequence in $B$ converging to 4?

Comment: @user2190298: That situation doesn’t arise: if $0<a<2$ for every $a\in A$, then $A$ isn’t dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Oh the shame. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2190298: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- If $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then $A+2013 = \{a+2013 \mid a \in A\}$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
- Union of dense sets is dense, in particular, $A+B = \bigcup_{b \in B}A+b$.

Good luck!